# Remove Path Fills Completely in D3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, d3.js, svg, gis

I am currently building a platform for mapping some data that require drawing lines between nodes in the map. For now, I have created those lines
([Picture 1 (`fill: none`)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN2fD.png)). Furthermore, I intend to add a click listener to the lines which I have also done. Unfortunately, it seems the path have a fill area that also listens to the events and overlapped on the other paths which make it impossible to click paths below it ([Picture 2 default fill attr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELxB2.png)). I have tried to set `fill: none` (as shown in the first picture) but it seems only removing the colours, not the fill area.
Here is my code to add the lines:

```
function createPath(company) {

  //Create Paths Line
  var linePathGenerator = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return d.y;
    })
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);

  // Add Path to the Line Layer
  var svgPath = layerArc.append("path")
    .attr("stroke", companyConfig[company].color)
    .attr("stroke-width", "1.5px")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .style("opacity", 0.6);


  var d = linePathGenerator(adjency[company])
  var line = svgPath.attr("d", d)

  // Click Listener 
  line
    .on('click', function() {
      if (!d3.select(this).classed("active")) {
        layerArc.selectAll('path')
          .attr("stroke-width", "1.5px")
          .style("opacity", 0.6);
        d3.select(this)
          .attr("stroke-width", 3)
          .style("opacity", 1)
          .attr("class", "active")
        d3.selectAll(".nodes svg circle")
          .style("stroke", 'none')
        var circles = d3.selectAll(".nodes svg")
        circles = circles.filter(function(d) {
          return d.value.company == company
        })
        circles.select('circle').style("stroke", 'white')
          .style("stroke-width", 2)
      } else {
        layerArc.selectAll('path')
          .attr("stroke-width", "1.5px")
          .style("opacity", 0.6)
          .attr("class", "deactive")
        d3.selectAll(".nodes svg circle")
          .style("stroke", 'none')
      }
    })

  var totalLength = svgPath.node().getTotalLength();

  svgPath
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
    .transition()
    .duration(4000)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0)

}
```

Anyone know how to remove the fill entirely? or any other suggestion on how I draw the lines in the same manner but without Path?

Comment: Stack snippet is for **running code** only, I edited your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Gerardo Furtado, this my first post actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you just want the listener to fire when the user clicks on the *stroke* of the path, not on its *fill* (the confusion arises because you're using the term *"line"*, which means another thing in a SVG).

If that's correct the solution is simple, you just need to set the [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) of those paths to `visibleStroke` or `stroke`:

```
.attr("pointer-events", "visibleStroke");
```

Here is a demo, you can click in the fill or outside the path and nothing happens, click on its stroke and the listener fires:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var path = svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", "M50,20 L250,20 L250,130 L50,130 Z")
  .style("fill", "teal")
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .style("stroke-width", 4)
  .attr("pointer-events", "visibleStroke")
  .on("click", function() {
    console.log("clicked")
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Also, it's worth mentioning that something is wrong in your code: if you set the fill to `none`, the default `pointer-events` should **not** fire. Here is a demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var path = svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", "M50,20 L250,20 L250,130 L50,130 Z")
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .style("stroke-width", 4)
  .on("click", function() {
    console.log("clicked")
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```